# Would the following mapStateToProps function create performance problems with redux connect()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would like to pass all the redux state into an easy to manage key on my props (I'm doing the same with the action creators). I would de-structure the state off the props that I actually need in the components that would consume them. Would the following create performance problems?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({ reduxState: {...state}})
```

Inside my component I would destructure the state to consume like:

```
const {
  geosuggestLocation,
  mapLocationDetails,
  userWants,
  smartySuggestion,
  geocodeAddress
} = this.props.reduxState
```

So far, everything works as expected, I would just like to know if it's a pattern I can continue to use without performance issues later down the road.

Comment: your are mapping your whole redux state to a single component. There are definitely some de-composition you can do. But if you are comparing it  as opposed to  `mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({...state})`, the performance shouldn't differ.

Comment: By the way, are you intentially shallow-cloning `state` by writing `{...state}` ? Because babel will transpile that to a `_extends` call which obviously takes more time than simply passing the object. Shallow cloning would only make sense if you can't ensure any other code tries to modify the object. I don't think (prove me wrong!) react would do that in the `{reduxState: state}` case. And neither should you ;)